# Fetch csv file from https using python

Tags: python, database, https, python-requests

This is a fairly simple problem:

Fetch a csv file from an https url using python. The only allowed source to get it is:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1535760000&period2=1693440000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true

If you enter the website in your browser, the download begins automatecally

I tried using requests.get() but im getting error 403.

Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1535760000&period2=1693440000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"

response = requests.get(url)

print(response)
```

output: <Response [403]>

Comment: The website decided you're a robot and doesn't want to talk to you.

Comment: ahahaah is that for real? Is there a way to bypass this>

Comment: This may help you ! (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python)

Comment: I saw that, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the headers so that website doesn't reject the request based on `User-Agent` field.

```py
import requests
url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1535760000&period2=1693440000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.content.decode())
```

This should print the comma separated valued fetched from the resource.

Comment: Wow, thanks mate that actually worked! I am a bit worried about the User-Agent though, do I need to adjust it based on my own OS?

Comment: Nah I don't think so it is checked based on OS. It's an HTTP request at the end, could be crafted from any where.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1535760000&period2=1693440000&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"

response = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'myfilename.csv')

print(response)
```